# MySQL: Use a LIMIT for a JOIN table added

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

### View

The view of the app contains a *page* which shows a bunch of carousels (each carousel = *a tag*), each of each should contain 5 *products*:

```
+-------------------------------------+
|Page                                 |
|+-----------------------------------+|
||Tag1                               ||
||+--------+ +--------+    +--------+||
|||Product1| |Product2| .. |Product5|||
||+--------+ +--------+    +--------+||
|+-----------------------------------+|
|...                                  |
|+-----------------------------------+|
||TagN                               ||
||...                                ||
+-------------------------------------+
```

### Database

#### pages

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(16) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

#### pages_tags

```
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| page_id      | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tag_id       | int(11)    | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| position     | tinyint(4) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `pages_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `page_id` (`page_id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `pages_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`) REFERENCES `pages` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `pages_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=663 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

#### tags

```
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=149 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

#### products_tags

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| product_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tag_id     | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `products_tags` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  KEY `bouquet_id` (`product_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `products_tags_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `products_tags_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5698 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

#### products

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(128) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=335 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

### Goal

The goal is to get an output which will contain **all tags on the page, containing the max of 5 products each**.

### Query

Here is the query I've got before getting stuck:

```
SELECT t.name, p.name 
FROM pages a 
LEFT JOIN pages_tags a_t ON a_t.page_id = a.id 
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = a_t.tag_id 
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.id = (
  SELECT p_t.product_id FROM products_tags p_t WHERE p_t.tag_id = t.id LIMIT 1
);`
```

### Problems

1. Unable to use `limit 5`:

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

2. Unable to use `in` + `limit`:

> ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Help needed.

---

### What I want to return (example)

- page

  - tag1

    - product1
    - product2
    - product3
    - product4
    - product5
  - tag2

    - product6
    - product7
    - product8
    - product9
    - product10
  - ...
  - tagN

    - productK
    - productL (but always the max of 5)

Comment: You are using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY`.  That is awkward.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: This is for SSR (Server Side Rendering), levering the computation from JavaScript to DB - saves huge amounts of time under current circumstances. So far DB queries saved a lot of time. If this kind of query to to complex (for the community experts as well) - will have to use a different strategy.

Comment: Consider to upgrade to MySQL 8.0+ or MariaDB 10.2+ and use window functions.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do what you want with a scalar subquery:

```
p.id <= (SELECT p_t.product_id
         FROM products_tags p_t
         WHERE p_t.tag_id = t.id 
         ORDER BY p_t.product_id
         LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
        )
```

However, this does not work if there are fewer than 5 rows.  In that case, you can use `coalesce()`:

```
p.id <= COALESCE( (SELECT p_t.product_id
                   FROM products_tags p_t
                   WHERE p_t.tag_id = t.id 
                   ORDER BY p_t.product_id
                   LIMIT 1 OFFSET 4
                  ), p.id
                )
```

Note:  This assumes that you want the product ids in order.

Comment: Getting: `ERROR 1235 (42000): This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`. Updated description. Note, that the goal is to return up to 5 products for each tag.

Comment: ANY is not supported for subqueries with LIMIT. But you don't need it.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel . . . <face palm>:  I know I have tested and used this construct and I really did think that was with MySQL.  Clearly, wrong on that last point.